# regex transform scientific notation to geocoordinate

Tags: java, regex

How can I transform a number of:

```
1.5635679E7
```

to

```
15.635679
```

i.e. scientific notation double to geocoordinate? I thought that using a regex might be a great idea, however I can't get it to transform the `.` to the right position in the string:
https://regex101.com/r/ZhZ7uu/1
only gives
`1` and `5635679`.

The flavor of regex is java.

Comment: what will be your rouptut if `1.5635679E9` ? what is the range of `E`?

Comment: The function below `15.635679` generates this. Which is fine for me as this return valid spatial coordinates (at lest here in my area where I am interested in .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`String p1 = (\\.)(\\d);`

and then:

```
Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(p1);
r1.replaceAll("$2$1");
```

> Note the `"$2$1"` will swap the positions of `.` and `5`

[**Here is a working example**](https://repl.it/@RahulVerma8/SwappingPositions)

Comment: A single group seems to be enough (and more efficient): `(\\.\\d)` and replace: `$1`